# How do I display alert messages to the side of the screen in a way that they do not overlap each other?

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I am setting up a component in Laravel with Blade that sends error messages like the following:

[image]

The problem is that when there are more than one error, the alerts overlap each other and only the first one is visible, while the rest are hidden as seen in the previous image.

I have tried several configurations with Alpinejs and JavaScript, but I have not been able to visually separate the alerts on the screen so that they appear one below the other, but all of them are visible.

The last code that I used with Alpinejs was the following:

```
@if ($messages)
    <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'fixed top-0 right-0 mt-3 mr-3 space-y-2 z-50']) }}>
        @foreach ((array) $messages as $key => $message)
            <div class="flex p-4 mb-4 text-white bg-red-500 border-t-4 border-red-700 rounded-lg shadow-lg" role="alert" x-data="{ show: false }" x-show="show" x-transition x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true; setTimeout(() => show = false, 5000); }, {{ $key }} * 6000); $nextTick(() => $el.style.transform = 'translateY(' + ({{ $key }} * ($el.offsetHeight + 16)) + 'px)')">
                <svg class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                <button @click="show = false" class="ml-auto text-lg font-semibold">&times;</button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Later, I tried with a JavaScript script, but the result is still the same. Here is the code:

```
@if ($messages)
    <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'fixed top-0 right-0 mt-3 mr-3 space-y-2 z-50']) }} id="alert-container">
        @foreach ((array) $messages as $key => $message)
            <div id="alert-{{ $key }}" class="alert hidden flex p-4 mb-4 text-white bg-red-500 border-t-4 border-red-700 rounded-lg shadow-lg" role="alert">
                <svg class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                <button onclick="hideAlert({{ $key }})" class="ml-auto text-lg font-semibold">&times;</button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <script>
        function showAlert(key, delay) {
            const alertElement = document.getElementById('alert-' + key);
            alertElement.classList.remove('hidden');

            const alerts = document.getElementsByClassName('alert');
            let offsetY = 0;

            for (let i = 0; i < key; i++) {
                offsetY += alerts[i].offsetHeight + 16;
            }

            alertElement.style.transform = 'translateY(' + offsetY + 'px)';

            setTimeout(() => {
                hideAlert(key);
            }, delay);
        }

        function hideAlert(key) {
            const alertElement = document.getElementById('alert-' + key);
            alertElement.classList.add('hidden');
        }

        @foreach ((array) $messages as $key => $message)
            setTimeout(() => {
                showAlert({{ $key }}, 5000);
            }, {{ $key }} * 6000);
        @endforeach
    </script>
@endif
```

I appreciate your help in indicating what I need to correct in the code so that the alerts are displayed on the screen one below the other without overlapping. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using toastr.js for your notifications. It is an easy-to-implement solution that doesn't overlap with other elements on the page. Additionally, you can configure the notifications to appear on the bottom-left of the screen.

https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html